# Incorrect cast to char element of a string derived from a number

Tags: c#, char

```
static void Main()
{
    int a = 612345;
    string b = Convert.ToString(a);
    char c = Convert.ToChar(b[0]);
    int d = Convert.ToInt32(c);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

When doing this operation, I would like to get the output "6", but I get "54". Going through the program with a debugger, I saw this.

[image: debugger]

Where `char c` generally takes the number `54` if the zero element of the array is `6`? How can I fix this?

I apologize in advance if my question seems stupid and incorrect to someone, I am new to programming. (But I understand that from a practical point of view, all these conversions are meaningless. This is precisely the learning task for a better understanding of the language)

Comment: Don't use the `Convert` class. To convert between numeric types use the cast operator and to convert from a `String` value to a numeric type use `DestinationType.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each character has a code, and *some* characters have corresponding numeric value, e.g.

```
char : code : value
-------------------
 '0' :   48 :     0
 '6' :   54 :     6
 'A' :   65 :    -1 (default value when character doesn't have numeric value)
 '¾' :  190 :  0.75 (note, that numeric value is a floating point value here)
```

So far so good, the most accurate way to obtain the numeric value is [char.GetNumericValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=net-6.0#system-char-getnumericvalue(system-char)):

```
char c = '¾';
      
double result = char.GetNumericValue(c);
```

However, in case of `'0' .. '9'` range you can put it as `c - '0'`, e.g.

```
char c = '6';
      
int result = c - '0';
```

In your case

```
int d = b[0] - '0';
```

alternative

```
int d = (int) char.GetNumericValue(b, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

54 is the ASCII code of 6. Your problem is because a char is really not that different from a small integer. Do this instead:

```cs
int a = 612345;
string b = a.ToString();
int d = Int32.Parse(b[0].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

You can call `ToString()` on almost anything in C#, so that conversion is easy. Use `Int32.Parse` to turn your char into an int and call `ToString` on the char to make `Parse` accept it, since it doesn't take char.

**EDIT**
To see that char is really just an integer underneath, you can actually change your original code like this:

```cs
int d = Convert.ToInt32(c)-'0';
```

and still get 6.

Comment: This works too `int d = b[0] - '0';`